# Why are sections of Cassini photographs blurred?

Tags: moons, imaging, cassini

In [this photograph](http://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/jpegMod/PIA19057_modest.jpg) of [Rhea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhea_(moon)), taken by the Cassini orbiter, there are sections near the terminator that are very blurred, a stark contrast from the crisp sharpness of the rest of the image. The blurred sections look polygonal in shape, with defined edges.

[image: 'Return to Rhea' (PIA19057). Zoomed in to the terminator, blurred portion highlighted. Courtesy NASA JPL]
<sup>Return to Rhea (PIA19057). Zoomed in to the terminator, blurred portion highlighted. Courtesy [NASA JPL](http://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA19057).</sup>

**Why are these portions blurred?** My theory is that Cassini could not take photographs of those regions with its narrow-field camera, and hence used wide-field data instead. **Am I right?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your guess is correct.  To quote [NASA's page](http://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA19057),

> The mosaics each consist of multiple narrow-angle camera (NAC) images with data from the wide-angle camera used to fill in areas where NAC data was not available.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Andy, I got more than enough information :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are composites of WAC and NAC images. The camera operation planners do their best to cover a target sufficient for good science, but sometimes time or data volume constraints prevent catching every part of an object.

The [image caption](http://www.ciclops.org/view.php?id=8030) on the CICLOPS site says "The mosaics each consist of multiple narrow-angle camera (NAC) images with data from the wide-angle camera used to fill in areas where NAC data was not available."